# Entity Framework EDMX not updating connection string in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET web application that uses Entity Framework for database access. I've encountered an issue where I updated the connection string in my `web.config` file to point to a new database, but when I refresh the EDMX diagram, it still appears to be connected to the old database.

Here's a rundown of my actions and setup:

I updated the connection string in my `web.config` file located in the root directory of the web application.

The application is using Entity Framework version 6.1.3 and .NET Framework 4.5.

Despite these updates, the EDMX model seems to be linked to the previous database schema. I have a new column in a table of the new DB, although the table already exists in the old DB the new column doesn't, so when I refresh I'm not able to see the new column in the diagram. Both DBs are in the same server.

I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

- Refreshed the EDMX model from the database via the "Update Model from Database" option in Visual Studio.
- Verified that the application uses the updated connection string during runtime, and it successfully connects to the correct database.

However, the EDMX diagram continues to display the outdated schema from the prior database. Are there any additional steps I should take to ensure the EDMX model reflects the new connection string?

Comment: Presumably the EDMX is in another assembly so it has its own connection string. IIRC you can check its connection string in the EDMX's properties in VS.

Comment: It is indeed showing the connection string of the old DB